# How to pass model's object to thymeleaf, and to contorller as hidden in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How to pass model's object to thymeleaf, and to contorller as hidden in thymeleaf?

```
        model.addAttribute("member", member);
        model.addAttribute("item", item);
        model.addAttribute("poi", poi);
        model.addAttribute("myModel", myModel);
        model.addAttribute("allPlans", allPlans);
        model.addAttribute("allPois", allPois);
        model.addAttribute("itemParam",itemParam);
```

This is controller1.

controller1 passes 7 objects to item.

```
        <input type="hidden" th:field=${member}>
        <input type="hidden" th:field=${item}>
        <input type="hidden" th:field=${poi}>
        <input type="hidden" th:field=${myModel}>
        <input type="hidden" th:field=${allPlans}>
        <input type="hidden" th:field=${allPois}>
        <input type="hidden" th:field=${itemParam}>
```

This is the thymeleaf code.

Here is the result:

```
        <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="">
```

How can I pass 7 objects intact to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two ways to do this:

1. Method 1

Instead of using `th:field` use `html` `id` & `name`. Set value using `th:value`

```html
<input type="hidden" id="yourId1" name="yourName1" th:value="${item}">
```

2. Method 2: Use [preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing)

```html
<input type="hidden" th:field="__${item}__">
```